# Правильно ли такое исполнение?

Tags: javascript, jquery, инспекция-кода

Добрый день! Посмотрите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я сделал? Это у меня скрипт для адаптации таблиц. И мне нужно, чтобы он работал при разрешении экрана менее 800 пикс. Для чего я и взял весь скрипт в:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
```

Правильно ли такое решение? Благодарю!

```
$(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
$.fn.lazyResponsiveTable = function( options ) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        thead: 'thead',
        tbody: 'tbody',
    }, options);
    var $table = $(this);
    var $thead = $table.find(settings.thead);
    var $tbody = $table.find(settings.tbody);
$thead.find('th').each( function() {
    var data = $(this).text();
    if( ! $(this).attr('data-table')) {
        $(this).attr('data-table',data);
    }
});
$tbody.find('td').each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    var data = $thead.find('th:eq('+index+')').attr('data-table');
        $(this).attr('data-table',data);
});
};
$('.table').lazyResponsiveTable();
    }
});
```

Comment: "при разрешении экрана" или при размере окна?

Comment: лучше использовать outerWidth() так как width() не учитывает отступы внутри элемента и вне его

Comment: outerwidth() не работает в mozille, лол и зачем делать extend обьекта, вы понимаете зачем вообще нужен extend ? и each функия совсем не нужна

Comment: @Lieutenant Jim Dangle в каком смысле он не работает в mozille? можно привести пример кода, где outerWidth() не будет работать в mozille?